# Sort Red, Green Blue using C

Tags: c

this is my first time using Stack Overflow, and I must warn you that I only started to learn C earlier this week. I am trying to write a simple program that will find which color has the greatest value out of the RGB spectrum. It has a manual input for each color, but when It is finished, I am getting 2 odd numbers ranging in the millions. Could somebody help a noob? Here is the code that I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mm, m;
    int hh, h;
    int r, g, b, c;

    printf("Enter Value For Red (0-255)\n");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Enter Value For Green (0-255)\n");
    scanf("%d", &g);
    printf("Enter Value For Blue (0-255)\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);


    if ( r > g );
        if ( r > b );
            mm = r;
            if ( g > b );
                m = b;
            if ( b > g );
                m = g;
       if ( r < b );
            mm = b;
            m = g;
    if ( g > r );
        if ( g > b );
            mm = g;
            if ( r > b );
                m = b;
            if ( b > r );
                m = r;
        if ( g < b );
            mm = b;
            m = r;

    printf("%d\n", &mm);
    printf("%d\n", &m);
}
```

Comment: Please next time read the documentation of the functions you're trying to use. Also, there are plenty of examples about using `printf()`.

Comment: Apart from the `printf` arguments of the wrong type, you don't treat the case of two (or three) equal values, then `mm` and `m` remain uninitialised.

Comment: Adding to @DanielFischer s comments, your `if` statements are also all wrong. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%d\n", &mm);
printf("%d\n", &m);
```

Should be:

```
printf("%d\n", mm);
printf("%d\n", m);
```

The `&` gets the address of the variable. When you're *setting* a variable via `scanf()` you need to give the address so that it can be set. When you're *printting* the value of a variable via `printf()` you need to just provide the name, not the address.

What you're seeing right now is the address of where your variables are stored on the stack as a decimal number.

---

Side note, your code doesn't work the way you think it does:

```
if ( r > g );
    if ( r > b );
        mm = r;
        if ( g > b );
            m = b;
        if ( b > g );
            m = g;
   if ( r < b );
        mm = b;
        m = g;
```

It takes more then indentation to get this working, right now it's doing the following:

```
mm = r;
m = b;
m = g;
mm = b;
...
```

everytime you run it, because the if's are being chucked. You can't have `;` after an `if` statement or it doesn't do what's below it. Also use curly brackets `{ }` to make a scope to do more then one thing:

```
if ( r > g )
{
    if ( r > b )
    {
        mm = r;
        if ( g > b )
            m = b;
        if ( b > g )
            m = g;
   }
   if ( r < b )
   {
        mm = b;
        m = g;
    ...
```

Is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason `scanf()` accepts pointers to its arguments: it has to modify them.

However, `printf()` does not modify its arguments (generally... - there are exceptions), so you don't have to pass it pointers. Change

```
printf("%d\n", &mm);
printf("%d\n", &m);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", mm);
printf("%d\n", m);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of { and } after your ifs. Your form of `if ( r > g );` does hardly work. Especially the semi-colons are wrong here.